# How to use k8s secrets for BasicAuth in OpenSearch Datascource in Grafana Helm chart Values file?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I’m trying to integrate AWS OpenSearch with self managed Grafana deployed via Helm charts for tracking application metrics.
I created k8s generic secret and I want to use those secrets for openSearch datasource auth but I’m not sure how to use k8s secrets for basic auth for OpenSearch integration with Grafana.

```yaml
datasources:
- name: OpenSearch
type: grafana-opensearch-datasource
url: https://my-os.com/
basicAuth: true
basicAuthUser: esadmin
secureJsonData:
basicAuthPassword:
isDefault: false
jsonData:
tlsAuth: false
tlsSkipVerify: true
#osVersion: ‘OpenSearch_1.3’
database: ‘dashboard*’
interval: Daily
timeField: ‘@timestamp’
version: ‘1.3.2’
flavor: ‘opensearch’
```

Anyone has any leads on this? Thank you!

Comment: You question seems to be off-topic, since it is not about development, but about configuration. Consider [sf] or [devops.se] instead.